# Finding a orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

In an Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$, there is an linear operator $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to\mathbb{R}^3$ with a matrix
$$A=
\left[\begin{matrix}                                        
                 1 & -2 & -2 \\
                -2 &  1 & -2 \\
                -2 & -2 &  1  \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Find the orthonormal basis of the matrix $D$ of $f$ which is diagonal and the matrix of $D$.

Comment: Step one.  Find a diagonalization for A,  Step 2: apply the Graham-Schmidt process.  Which of these is troubling you?  If it is 2) then show us 1) and the results you are getting.  If it is 1) then what is the characteristic polynomial?  There is at least 1 eigenvalue you should be able to guess.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ is symmetric, the eigenvalues are real and $A$ is diagonalizable with an orthonormal basis by the spectral theorem. By the lack of information (what you have already tried and so on...) here are the basic steps:

- Calculate the characteristic polynomial of $A$
- Calculate a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$
- Orthonormalize this basis using Gram-Schmidt